# Get Data PhoneNumber from Google API using React OAuht

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have apps for registration then i need that feature can handle new registration using Google API.
I have set up it on google console admin and add in the Scope part to get phonenumber by using 'PhonenNumber.read' API like this image below

Then, in react application, i am using @react-oauth/google as library to call it.

Could you teach me how to get phonenumber since the data that i get from that API currently only basic email and profile, which i also need data from phone number too?

Here is my code

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  GoogleOAuthProvider,
  GoogleLogin,
  useGoogleLogin,
} from "@react-oauth/google";
import "./App.css";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import google from "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";

function App() {
  f
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="App"
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flex: 1,
          height: "100vh",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        Hi There, Welcome
        <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="102719035032-plab3dv29ukb37k4kubscgsdgnlibs94.apps.googleusercontent.com">
          <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={(credentialResponse) => {
              let data = jwtDecode(credentialResponse.credential);
              console.log(data);
            }}
            onError={() => {
              console.log("Login Failed");
            }}
          />
        </GoogleOAuthProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can get data phonenumber from google API